# how to test a react component after data is fetch in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react component that renders conditionally (renders if data is fetched otherwise returns null) and I want to test this with `jest & enzyme`. The problem that I'm having is I want to test one of the methods in the class but `.instance()` keeps returning null so it doesn't allow me to test the instance.

my code looks something like this

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData.then(() => 
            this.setState({ loaded: true });
        );
    }

    methodThatIWantToTest() {
        //do some stuff here
    }

    render() {
        if (this.loaded) {
            // render stuff here
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and in the test I want to test

```
describe('myComponent', () => {
   it('should do some stuff', () => {
      const shallowWrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>);
      const method = shallowWrapper.instance().methodThatIWantToTest();
      ....such and such

   });
});
```

but it looks like `MyComponent` only returns null so `shallowWrapper.instance()` returns null as well. I tried `shallowWrapper.update()` and many other things but it seems it doesn't want to render at all.. How do I wait for my component to be updated and then starts `expect` statement?

has anyone had a similar issue as mine and know how to work around this?

Comment: Can you try to not return `null` in your render method, but `<div />` instead?

Answer (score 1):

It is `render` result and not an instance that is `null`. `shallowWrapper.instance()` is an instance of component class, it cannot be `null` for stateful component. As [the reference](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html) states:

> Returns (React 16.x)
>
> ReactComponent: The stateful React component instance.
>
> null: If stateless React component was wrapped.

While `shallowWrapper.html()` will be initially `null` indeed.

There is a mistake in original code, it should be `this.state.loaded` and not `this.loaded`:

```
MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { loaded: false };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData.then(() => {
          this.setState({ loaded: true });
    });
  }

  methodThatIWantToTest() {
      //do some stuff here
  }

  render() {
      if (this.state.loaded) {
          return <p>hi</p>;
      } else {
          return null;
      }
  }
}
```

`componentDidMount` and `methodThatIWantToTest` should be preferably considered different units. They belong to different tests. In case `methodThatIWantToTest` is called in lifecycle hooks, it may be stubbed in `componentDidMount` test:

```
   it('should fetch data', async () => {
      const props = { fetchData: Promise.resolve('data') };
      const shallowWrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>);
      expect(shallowWrapper.html()).toBe(null);
      await props.fetchData;
      expect(shallowWrapper.html()).toBe('<p>hi</p>');
   });
```

Then the method can be tested separately. Lifecycle hooks can be disabled to reduce number of moving parts:

```
   it('should do some stuff', () => {
      const shallowWrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>, {disableLifecycleMethods: true});
      const result = shallowWrapper.instance().methodThatIWantToTest();
      expect(result).toBe(...);    
   });
```

Comment: thanks for finding my mistake and trying to help me out. but unfortunately, it's working :( i got `yield is a reserved word` for `await` and `{disableLifecycleMethods....}` doesn't resolve `.instance()` issue

Comment: actually, i'm using `redux` to export this class with `store` via `connect`. maybe that's why the test is failing..

Comment: *yield is a reserved word* is because `await` wasn't used in `async`, fixed that. *actually, i'm using redux to export this class with store via connect* - this is highly possible. Connected component isn't your component class, it's another component your component is wrapped with, it doesn't have `methodThatIWantToTest`. Consider testing your units in isolation. Your class is one unit. Connected class is another. Additional moving parts prevent you from detecting a troublemaker efficiently, which is a must for unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

---

myComponent.js

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props);
    this.state = { loaded: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData().then(() =>
      this.setState({ loaded: true })
    );
  }

  methodThatIWantToTest() {
    return 'result';
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loaded) {
      return <div>loaded</div>;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

---

myComponent.test.js

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import MyComponent from './myComponent';

describe('myComponent', () => {
  it('should do some stuff', async () => {
    const fetchData = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());
    const props = { fetchData };

    const shallowWrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>);
    expect(shallowWrapper.html()).toBe(null);

    expect(shallowWrapper.instance().methodThatIWantToTest()).toBe('result');

    // pause the test and let the event loop cycle so the callback
    // queued by then() within componentDidMount can run
    await Promise.resolve();

    expect(shallowWrapper.html()).toBe('<div>loaded</div>');
  });
});
```